# Sort this array based on custom criteria

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

```
array("name" => "",
      "uid" => "",
      "nid" => "",
      "vid" => "");
```

And I need it sorted like this:

```
array("nid" => "",
      "uid" => "",
      "vid" => "",
      "name" => "");
```

But I can't seem to figure out array_map, uksort()... or any others. THanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a sort as such, but if you are only looking at 4 keys then why not:

```
$newArray = array("nid" => $array["nid"], "uid" => $array["uid"], "vid" => $array["vid"], "name" => $array["name"]);
```

Comment: This ends up working best because sometimes the first array doesn't have all the keys, and I need the key to be present (even if the value is null), thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the [function reference](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php) for uksort?

Given that you want to sort an array alphabetically in ascending order by its keys but have the 'name' key last, this should work even if you add additional keys later:

```
<?php

class MySortHelper
{
    function sort_my_array($a, $b)
    {
        if ( $a == $b ) return 0;

        if ( $a == 'name' ) return 1;
        if ( $b == 'name' ) return -1;

        return ($a > $b) ? 1 : -1;
    }
}

// ...

$my_sort_helper = new MySortHelper();
uksort($my_array, array($my_sort_helper, 'sort_my_array'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [uksort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php).

```
function myksort($a, $b) {
    $korder = array('nid', 'uid', 'vid', 'name');
     return (array_search($a, $korder) < array_search($b, $korder)) : -1 ? 1;
}

uksort($array, 'myksort');
```